# Bibcite: How to sort publications by last name of first author?

Tags: views, 8

Bibcite module: I have a view which shows all publications and I'm using the citation field. But every publication is shown as many time as many authors it has. When I'm using aggregation (count distinct) on one of the sorting items only one publication per year is shown. Also sorting the list by "Contributor: Last name" doesn't work. What is the "official" way to sort publications by the last name of the first author? I have tried so many things now, but I'm not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The contributor field doesn't provide delta for sorting and filtering, so you have to apply a view hook to access the first last name:
https://www.drupal.org/project/bibcite/issues/3182978